# Proving that a system of ODEs has a focus at the origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates, stability-in-odes

> Prove that the following system of ODEs has a focus at the origin.
>
> $$\begin{aligned} \dot{x} &= -x^3-y^3\\
>                   \dot{y} &= x^3       \end{aligned}$$

Plotting the vector field confirms this fact. I've tried to convert the system to polar coordinates and I've shown that $\dot{\theta}\neq 0$ except at the origin. I believe it would suffice to show that

$$r(\theta+2\pi)-r(\theta) < 0$$

for al $\theta$ when close to the origin. However, this seems to involve expressing $r$ in terms of $\theta$, which I don't know how to do. Any help? Additionaly, is there an easier method? Thank you in advance.

I also had the following idea: according to the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$r(\theta+2\pi)-r(\theta)=\int_\theta^{\theta+2\pi}\frac{dr}{d\theta}d\theta$$ If only I could somehow show this is strictly less than $0$...

Comment: What do you mean by "focus"? Sorry for the basic question. I knew a focus was something related to the linearization of the system, which however is reduced to zero here...

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro *Focus* is a generally accepted term for an equilibrium of a planar vector field such that any positive half-orbit (for *stable focus*) or negative half-orbit (for *unstable focus*) converges to the equilibrium by winding  infinitely many times around it as $t\to\infty$/$t\to-\infty$.  The linearization of the field at the equilibrium having eigenvalues with nonzero imaginary parts and nonzero real parts is a sufficient condition for the equilibrium to be a focus (it is then sometimes referred to as *hyperbolic focus*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider a Lyapunov function of the form $V(x,y)=F(x)+G(y)$ with $F,G$ positive, convex, minimum in $0$, so that
$$
\dot V=F'(x)(-x^3-y^3)+G'(y)x^3
$$
The term that is not directly compatible with a center is the $y$ derivative. Thus to eliminate the last term one can try to get $$G'(y)x^3-F'(x)y^3=0.$$

---

To see what happens, left is a plot of several solution trajectories, while right the same solution are plotted using $(x|x|,y|y|)$ as coordinates, so that the level curves of $x^4+y^4=r^4$ in that picture would be circles.

[image]

Comment: How would the existence of such a Lyapunov function guarantee that each positive half-orbit close to the origin **winds around the origin infinitely many times** (which was the OP's problem)? From the property that $\dot{V}<0$ it follows, to me, only that such a positive half-orbit eventually reaches any (sufficiently close to the origin) level set of $V$, but without any hint as to the behavior between level sets. Perhaps one could use two Lyapunov functions: one responsible for attraction, and the other for winding.

Comment: Very nice approach! How did you create these plots?

Comment: @RayBern : python with odeint and some loops for the background rings and initial conditions. Needed some experimentation to get a suitable path length parametrization, in the given form the speed drops very fast giving short curves.

Comment: Responding to user539887, the function responsible for the winding is $\theta$ and since its derivative is non-zero, the trajectories wind around the origin.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I don't think this happens, since the norm of the vector field can get arbitrarily small as we approach the origin, since the vector field is induced by two homogeneous polynomials

Comment: @RayBern To me, the positivity of $\dot{\theta}$ *alone* does not suffice to show that the equilibrium is a focus: it could somehow happen that $\dot{\theta}>0$ but it converges to zero when we approach the origin, and when $\dot{\theta}$ tends to zero "faster" than the positive half-orbit approaches the equilibrium then I can imagine that there is no infinite winding. What is your formula for $\dot{\theta}$?

Comment: $\dot{\theta}=\frac{x\dot{y}-y\dot{x}}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x^4+y^4+yx^3}{x^2+y^2}$ is the formula I used. It can be shown that it is positive except at the origin. Your comment makes me wonder what else is needed to show this is a focus. Indeed, it is the case that $\dot{\theta}\to0$ as $x^2+y^2\to0$.

Comment: It can be shown that $\dot{\theta}\geq (\frac{1}{4}x^4+\frac{3}{4}y^4)/(x^2+y^2)$ through Young's inequality. It might help to solve the problem

Comment: @RayBern It seems that the time needed for a point to make a full rotation behaves as the reciprocal of the square of its distance to the origin. Now it is to be hoped that the point should not be attracted too strongly!